# Setting L2tp connection credential via PS Add-VpnConnection - How?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, l2tp

Pre warning i'm a powershell noob so do forgive me if this is an obvious one... but i have been struggling for the past few hours and i'm still no closer to getting this to work.

As the title suggests i'm trying to add an L2tp VPN connection via powershell using the Add-VpnConnection Cmdlt. The connection does get added to windows with my pre-shared key, so a good start, however i have no idea how to populate the username and password for the vpn like i do on the gui.

My original Add-VpnConnection line looked like:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name $User -ServerAddress $compIP -TunnelType L2tp -L2tpPsk $VPNPresharedKey -RememberCredential
```

To try and prompt for credentials I did:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name $User -ServerAddress $compIP -TunnelType L2tp -L2tpPsk $VPNPresharedKey -EncryptionLevel Optional -AuthenticationMethod Eap -EapConfigXmlStream $((New-EapConfiguration -UseWinlogonCredential).EapConfigXmlStream) -SplitTunneling -Force
```

But this seems to do nothing more than my first attempt did.

To Clarify, if i was doing this via the GUI it would be these fields i'm trying to populate with this script:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGwO2.jpg

Myself or another tech will be entering the string of the username and password for the VPN in the variables at the start of my script, and i already have a $Credential object that passes these. My question is how do i pass this to the Add-VpnConnection CMDlt ?

Thanks in advance!

(Full script: https://pastebin.com/22V5MEjj )

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted # Allows scripts to be run if cust exec policy is still active despite running as admin,


$InstallationPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\Company Product\Product.exe.Config"

##newDBinfo - Edit this:
$User = "" #Enter User here e.g Bob
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Password123" -AsPlainText -Force #Enter the password in plain text here
$compIP = "Enter Customer IP here" # Enter cust instance Public IP here
$VPNPresharedKey = "Enter Customer preshared key here" # Enter cust Pre Shared key here





$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

Add-VpnConnection -Name $User -ServerAddress $compIP -TunnelType L2tp -L2tpPsk $VPNPresharedKey -RememberCredential  #-AuthenticationMethod Pap
```